# Attaching jQuery events to angular components when they load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm coding a website using `Angular JS 1.5` and making heavy use of the new `component` directive; So far, it is great. I love the components system.

But I'm having a bit of trouble getting **`jQuery 3.0`** and `angular` components to talk to each other. Take this code, for instance;

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[animate-bounce]').velocity({
            translateY: '10px'
        }, {
            loop: true
        }).velocity('reverse');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This works fine on a normal page, but because of the nature of how `component` works, it doesn't apply to components that are instantiated after `$(document).ready`. That makes sense, of course. They don't exist, so it can't wire up to them.

I know about the component lifecycle; Specifically, the `$onInit` function. I know that I can hook the jQuery into that. But I'm wanting certain `jQuery` code to apply to any component that gets activated, and I wanted to try and keep the activation of it out of the `component` code.

Is this possible to do? Is there a 'global' `$onInit` for `component` that will let it run `jQuery` bindings when any component loads? Or is there a replacement for the old `live()` binding in `jQuery` that will trigger when new DOM is added?

Comment: You should use directives if you plan to have DOM manipulations and put that jQuery code inside directive link function.

Comment: I'm coding in such a way as to upgrade to angular 2, so I'm wanting to avoid directives. I also don't want the jQuery code coupled to an actual component, because it often needs to apply to HTML that appears in many components.

Comment: Directives are still available in Angular2.

However, you could just run your code in the controller. It will be executed once the controller is instantiated.

Eg: The "activate" function in the recommended part of still styleguide entry: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y034

Answer (score 0):

Ciel, your are attempting jQuery in Angular app where entire angular life cycle does not allow jQuery to interfere. Though it is not impossible to achieve but I will recommend to not use it due to following reasons.

- jQuery events and data bindings will not handled by Angular so forget about events and data removal.
- Handling JQ events extensively will kill the purpose of using Angular as framework.

-Workaround -

Try using Angular component as much as possible, you may give a hand using link and compile functions while creating an Angular component.

Hope this will hep